# I have accidentally removed my dev/sda while trying yo intall linux using unet bootin

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Since I wanted to install Linux alongside Windows 7 (without usb since my PC refuses to boot from usb or anything, so I decided to use Unet bootin) and then I made a mistake and removed `/dev/sda` and I can't boot to windows or Linux anymore. All I have is a Windows 7 CD that contains repair pc options. How can I fix my problem? I don't want to end up erasing my data and I can't use terminal. Also did I lose my data?

Comment: How can I use the "testdisk" thing, knowing I don't have Linux installed.

Comment: Now that I'm not posting on a smartphone, I turned my comment into a more fleshed-out answer.

Comment: What do you mean "I removed /dev/sda"?

Comment: Believe you would need to update with a step by step recall of what you did *from starting Unet Bootin to where you are at now*. Also: *"All I have is a Windows 7 CD that contains repair PC options"* – does this mean you do not have access to another computer where you can create a live CD? Is this a laptop or stationary PC? What model?

Comment: Assume you used the *"the "Hard Disk" install mode"* in Unet Bootin - and then proceeded from Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question will be hard to answer without knowing exactly what you did to "remove /dev/sda."

If you only overwrote the partition table, the `testdisk` utility might be able to recover it. But if the installation attempt went any further than that, some of your data may already be overwritten and lost forever. Even so, you might still be able to recover *some* of your files using `photorec` or similar recovery software.

Both [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) are free and run on Linux, MacOS, Windows and several other OSs. There are even [live CDs that include one or both of those tools.](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd)

Since your own computer's operating systems are not functional right now, you might have to go to another computer to prepare your live boot media.

It might even be a good idea to remove the system disk from your own computer and plug it as a second disk to another computer with a working OS, as that would probably make the recovery process easier.